# Media Element Wordpress plugin conflict with JetPack

Tags: wordpress, conflict, mediaelement.js

I'm having a problem with my Jetpack (v1.3.4) and MediaElements.js (v2.7.0 - also tested with v2.9.1) plugins. MediaElements is my audio and video player of choice (a great plugin) but there seems to be an incompatibility with the Jetpack plugin.

I have the MediaElements and Jetpack plugins installed and both are deactivated. I activate MediaElements and the audio player works fine (see page http://music.woolston.com.au/new-work-in-progress/). Even after I activate Jetpack, MediaElements continues to work. As soon as I connect Jetpack to my site (completed the "Connect to Workpress.com" logon process), the MediaElements plugin stops working.

I'd appreciate any help that you can give. I have logged a bug with Jetpack support too ( http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/conflict-with-other-plugin?replies=1#return ).

Answer (score 0):

from: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/

Shortcode Options
Alternatives

If you have a plugin that conflicts with MediaElement.js, you can also use the short codes

[mejsvideo src="http://mysite.com/mymedia.mp4" width="640" height="360"]
[mejsaudio src="http://mysite.com/mymedia.mp3"]

...solves problem with JetPack for me.